# Не работает ajax в php файле

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте. Есть код:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "ok.php", //путь к твоему скрипту
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response){
                $("#content").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`<a href="#" id="link" onclick="return false">Ссылка</a>`
при нажатии на ссылку должен выполниться код из файла **ok.php**, там идут запросы в базу.
Так вот, если этот *ajax* код стоит в *.html* файле, то при нажатии на ссылку запросы в базу из файла ok.php выполняются, а если этот код поставить в *.php* файл, то запросы из файла ok.php не выполняются. 
Как сделать чтоб этот код работал в *.php* файле?

Comment: А как вы умудряетесь нажать на ссылку, если у вас код размещен в php файле? :) P.S. А если без шуток, то откройте консоль и перезагрузите файл в браузере. Посмотрите на ошибки выполнения javascript.

Comment: @Visman что значит *как вы умудряетесь нажать на ссылку, если у вас код размещен в php файле?* ссылка то активна, просто вывожу ее в echo '<a href="#" id="link" onclick="return false">Ссылка</a>';

Comment: Читайте мой P.S. в комментарии.

Comment: @Visman не подскажете как открыть консоль?

Comment: В гугль введите название вашего браузера и "консоль ошибок"

Comment: @Visman я так понял это ошибка **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Comment: Вероятно jQuery отсутствует на странице.

Comment: @Visman а как его добавить?

Comment: А как он у вас в html файле добавлен?

Comment: @Visman точно так же

Comment: По тому куску кода, который вы предоставили в вопросе, я не могу сказать каким образом у вас подключает jQuery на странице при ее генерации в php файле.

Comment: @Visman вот код *.html* файла: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url: "img.php", //путь к твоему скрипту
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response){
     $("#content").html(response);
    }
   });
  });
 });
</script>
<a href="#" id="link" onclick="return false">Ссылка</a>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Файл js.js это jQuery?

Comment: @Visman да, это он

Comment: Значит он не загружается. Через инструменты разработчика в браузере посмотрите как загрузка проходит (вкладка сеть или что-то похожее по названию).

Answer (score 1):

Тут два варианта:
1. Либо файлы у вас находятся в разных директориях php и html.
2. Либо в php файле у вас не подключен jQuery, либо путь к нему неверный.